# Are pointer addresses in a specific application same on different computers?

Tags: windows

You can use applications like Cheat Engine to find and manipulate different values in an application. However when you then close and reopen the application, it's likely that the previous addresses has changed. This would force me to find the new address in order to manipulate the value again.

If I find a pointer address in the application that is pointing to a specific place, it would allow me to easily then find the other address the value that you want to change.

As far as I understand it, the pointer address would not change when I restart the application.

My question is: Would my address to the pointer, for that application be the same on another computer?

If that is true, could windows OS, for example, windows 10 and windows 7 differentiate?

Comment: The pointer (in virtual program memory) will change if the application uses ASLR. This is a security feature invented to prevent simple attacks that use pre-calculated static addresses. For some applications on some systems ASLR can be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using absolute RAM addresses, then the answer is No.
The operating system tries to randomize allocated memory pages,
for the purpose of defeating exactly that kind of hacking.

If you are using relative offsets to the start of the program space,
meaning using program addressing such that the first program byte is at offset zero,
then the answer is Yes, such an address will stay the same across invocations
and Windows versions.

The answer for any loaded DLL is No, since Windows also randomizes
the addresses in the program space into which DLLs are loaded, and for the same reason
of security.

The answer is the same for Windows 7 and above.